# Comparing vectors and chosing common elements java

Tags: java, arrays, string, vector, compare

I want to compare a vector of strings with another vector or array. The point is that, depending on something, I will add to an array/vector some strings. Then, I want to compare it with another vector (this is alredy a vector, the method I use returns it that way) and save the common elements in a vector (it should be a vector or could be casted later).

I don't know if I can do it using vectors or if I should convert my vector to another type (array, list) to do the comparaison. Any ideas?

Comment: just fyi, nobody in the real world uses Vector - it's a broken relic. Use List.

Comment: One of the "lists" must be a Vector, because the method returns it that way. An option could be to cast it to List, do the comparaison and then cast the common elements List to a Vector again, because it must be a Vector for another method...

Comment: Is a SIP program using jsip libraries, and working with SDP load most of the times saves the information in Vector. In this case, the media formats information...

Answer (score 0):

To pull out common elements you can use [Vector.retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Retains only the elements in this Vector that are contained in the
>   specified Collection. In other words,   removes from this Vector all
>   of its elements that are not contained in the specified Collection.
>   **Returns:** true if this Vector changed as a result of the call

```
v1.retainAll(v2) //v1 will contain common elements only after this
```

**SideNote**: It uses `.equals()` under the hood

Comment: So, if I safe my info in a vector (v2) and do v1.retainAll(v2), now in v1 I'll only have the common elements v1Uv2?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Vector commonItems = new Vector();
Iterator vector1 = (whateverThefirstvectoris).itr();
Iterator vector2 = (whateverThesecondvectoris).itr();

while(vector1.hasNext())
{
    Object temp = new Object;
    temp = vector1.next();
    while(vector2.hasNext())
    {
        if(vector2.next().equals(temp))
        {
            commonItems.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The other answer seems to be more simple and fast, but if it doesn't work properly I'll try this too! Thank you anyway!